# How to redirect to home page if I click back button after login in angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, route-provider

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Auth','$state', function ($rootScope, $location, Auth,$state) {

    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {          

        if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {
            console.log('DENY');
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
        }
        else {
            console.log('ALLOW');
            $state.go('dashboard.admin');
        }
    });
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {


    if (!Auth.isLoggedIn()) {

        console.log('DENY');
        event.preventDefault();
        $state.go('login');
    }
    else {
        console.log('ALLOW');
        if($state.includes('login')) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
        $state.go('dashboard.admin');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$window.location.href = "homePageUrl";
```

Example:
  $window.location.href = "index.html";
Or you could use the $location service of angularJs
Link: [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location).
Use it where you feel inside whichever condition you want to load the home page,
**Assuming you are maintaining the session state**
Hope it helps
Regards
Shohil

Answer (score 0):

It depends which state you have defined for home.

```
$state.go('home');
```

Helpful links for you would be:-

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26200741/4361743